# Minikube hosted in oracle linux. A web application hosted within minikube not able to access the same from out side browser

Tags: linux, minikube

```
[root@master-node-1-sk ~]# kubectl describe services bank-cash-pro-gui-docker-image
Name:                     bank-cash-pro-gui-docker-image
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=bank-cash-pro-gui-docker-image
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=bank-cash-pro-gui-docker-image
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.109.95.142
IPs:                      10.109.95.142
LoadBalancer Ingress:     10.109.95.142
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  32537/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.6:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Below command works perfectly fine within server i.e.

```
curl http://192.168.49.2:32537
curl http://10.109.95.142:8080
```

But I am not able to access the application from browser from other machine. Any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: Minikube isn't a server or service. Accessing the Minikube local development environment from another host is already covered in depth here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180814/how-to-connect-to-minikube-services-from-outside